# Pausing an animation in matplotlib when saving to a video

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

First of all, this code runs exactly as I want to.  The problem is when it saves the animation as an MP4 then the video completely ignores the pause.  Is there any way to write the pause so that it will show up when saved as a video?  Is it a codec issue?

```py
import time
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from tkinter import *

# Setup a plot such that only the bottom spine is shown
def setup(axx):
    axx.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    axx.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    axx.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('#ffffff')
    axx.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    axx.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.NullLocator())
    axx.tick_params(which='major', width=3, length=20, colors='#ffffff', labelsize = 12)
    axx.tick_params(which='minor', width=1.5, length=10, colors='#ffffff')
    axx.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.05))
    axx.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.01))
    ax.xaxis.label.set_color('#ffffff')
    axx.set_ylim(0, 1)
    axx.patch.set_alpha(0.0)
    axx.set_xlim(1.2, 1.3)

def animate1(i):
    step1 = (1.3-1.283)/99  
    if i == 0:
        anim1.event_source.stop()
        time.sleep(3)
        anim1.event_source.start()
    xpos1 = i * step1 + 1.283 
    point.set_xdata([xpos1])
    if i == 99:
        ax.text(0.975, 0.13, 1.3, fontsize=12, color='#ffff80', transform=ax.transAxes)
    return ax,

mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 3
mpl.rcParams["savefig.facecolor"] = "#2e5090"
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,2))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('#2e5090')  #So the preview background color matches the saved animation
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
x = 1.283
setup(ax)
pos1 = ax.get_position() # get the original position 
pos2 = [pos1.x0, pos1.y0 + 0.4,  pos1.width, pos1.height] 
ax.set_position(pos2) # set a new position
ax.text(0.79, 0.13, format(x, '.3f'), fontsize=12, color='#ffffff', transform=ax.transAxes)
point, = ax.plot(x, 0.055, color='#ffff80', marker='v', markersize='8')
firstpoint = ax.plot(x, 0.055, color='#ffffff', marker='v', markersize='8')
anim1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate1, frames=100, interval=1, blit=False, repeat = False)  
anim1.save('movingpoint.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

Comment: I don't have time to provide an answer right now, but you may try, instead of adding a `sleep()` to generate 3 identical frames (or however many you need to get a 3s static image with your framerate)

Comment: Yep, consider that mp4 video has a constant framerate (here, fps=30). Matplotlib has no interface for "pauses". Hence repeat the same image as long as you want to "pause".